# Toast is shown every time when device is rotate

Tags: android-architecture-components

In my Android app I use AAC.

Here my activity:

```java
public class AddTraderActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    AddTraderViewModel addTraderViewModel;
    private static final String TAG = AddTraderActivity.class.getName();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        AddTraderActivityBinding binding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.add_trader_activity);
        binding.setHandler(this);
        init();
    }

    private void init() {
        ViewModelProvider viewViewModelProvider = ViewModelProviders.of(this);
        addTraderViewModel = viewViewModelProvider.get(AddTraderViewModel.class);
        Observer<String> () {

            @Override
            public void onChanged (String message){
                Debug.d(TAG, "onChanged: message = " + message);
                Toast.makeText(AddTraderActivity.this, message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });
    }

    public void onClickStart() {
        EditText baseEditText = findViewById(R.id.baseEditText);
        EditText quoteEditText = findViewById(R.id.quoteEditText);
        addTraderViewModel.doClickStart(baseEditText.getText().toString(), quoteEditText.getText().toString());
    }
}
```

Here my ViewModel:

```java
public class AddTraderViewModel extends AndroidViewModel {
    private MutableLiveData<String> messageLiveData = new MutableLiveData<>();

    private static final String TAG = AddTraderViewModel.class.getName();

    public AddTraderViewModel(@NonNull Application application) {
        super(application);
    }

    public void doClickStart(String base, String quote) {
        Debug.d(TAG, "doClickStart: ");
        if (base.trim().isEmpty() || quote.trim().isEmpty()) {
            String message = getApplication().getApplicationContext().getString(R.string.please_input_all_fields);
            messageLiveData.setValue(message);
            return;
        }
    }

    public LiveData<String> getMessageLiveData() {
        return messageLiveData;
    }
}
```

So when I click on button on Activity call method `onClickStart()`
If any fields is empty the show toast. In the activity call method:

```
onChanged (String message)
```

Nice. It's work fine.

But the problem is, when I rotate the device in the activity method `onChanged(String message)` is called **AGAIN** and as result show toast. This happened on every rotation.
Why?

Answer (score 1):

This is the expected behaviour. If you want to avoid this you must set `message = ""` and keep an empty check before showing the toast.

A better way to use it is something like Event Wrapper or [SingleLiveEvent](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-architecture/blob/dev-todo-mvvm-live/todoapp/app/src/main/java/com/example/android/architecture/blueprints/todoapp/SingleLiveEvent.java)

Highly recommend you to read this [article](https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/livedata-with-snackbar-navigation-and-other-events-the-singleliveevent-case-ac2622673150). This explains why you are facing this and what are your options in detail.